# Form field not visible in IE8

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, search, z-index

I'm working on a website template and Internet Explorer is giving me a headache since I'm unable to display the search form field and button correctly. z-index in CSS is not doing much either. 
By the way, how can I move the input area after the loupe icon?

Check the website here:
http://gabrielmeono.com/yonature/

Chrome:

[image: In Chrome]

In IE8:

[image: In IE6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things:

1. IE8 does not support border-radius, which is being applied to that field.
2. Your CSS references a file that's missing, [border-radius.htc](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/) which is for adding rounded corners in "all major browsers other than IE."
3. You should be able to add a left padding value on the field to force the text further to the right. It may be safer to make a white, rounded container and position the search button and text field within it.

**Edit:** I was wrong; the border-radius (curved-corner) file should work for IE6-8.

Comment: Why you say that is missing? the file is referenced like this:
behavior: url(css/border-radius.htc);

Comment: Yes, the file is at the link above. Your stylesheet, however, is in /css/styles.css and from there it's looking for css/border-radius.htc. So really, your stylesheet is looking for http://gabrielmeono.com/yonature/css/css/border-radius.htc.

Comment: In other words, the relevant CSS rule should look like this: `behavior: url(border-radius.htc);`

Comment: Got it! The tip you gave me about the div behind the text field works just fine.

Comment: Matt, this is weird, I changed the address of the border-radious.cc and the rounded corners on IE disappeared, I returned the address as it was and the round corners are back. And I'm still clueless why the search bar is not showing up.

Comment: You might try adding an absolute link to the file since you know that works properly (gabrielmeono.com/yonature/css/css/border-radius.htc), just to see what happens. Poke around with Firebug and IE's web inspector and you might find something. My original answers (and alternate suggestion) are still my best guesses.

Comment: Thanks Matt, will do that. I was finally able to show the searchfield and button on IE, using z-index 0. I think I over-used z-index in other divs, removing them fixed the issue.